# Why is Illustrator CC adding backgrounds to my text boxes?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am working on a series of exercises from a text book that we are using in my college course.  We are to create text boxes using a grid system per the instructions in the book.  My problem is that all of my text boxes are appearing with backgrounds of a saturated shade of red.  They do not appear that way in the book.  How do I get rid of this?  When I go to the Print dialogue, the preview does not show the backgrounds.  [image: my artboard]

PS:  The cyan and magenta blocks are supposed to be there and are meant to be spacers.

Answer (score 2):

You've opened a file that uses fonts not installed on your system. A warning should have popped up when you opened the file. Don't ignore it, it will tell you which fonts you need. If you don't see a pop-up, you can access it under <kbd>Type > Resolve Missing Fonts</kbd>.

[image: Illustrator Missing Fonts dialog]